# R - finding the neighbors of neighbors and storing them in a unique adjacency matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, graph, igraph

`A` is an adjacency matrix stored as a matrix object:

```
                   #1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A <- matrix(data=c( 0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,  #1
                    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,  #2
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #3
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,  #4
                    0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,  #5
                    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,  #6
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #7
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #8
                    0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0 ),#9
                    nrow=9, ncol=9)
```

The graph of `A` looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to identify the neighbors of neighbors, and to create a new adjacency matrix `N` with values that capture the neighbors of some node `j` who are exactly one step away from a given node `i`.

In `A` for example, `3` is neighbors with `1`, and `1` is neighbors with `4` and `8`. But `3` is neighbors with neither `4` nor `8`. In the desired adjacency matrix `N`, I want the row/column representing `3` to contain a value of 1 for columns that represent nodes `4` and `8`, but *not* node `1`. The solution matrix `N` should look like this:

```
                   #1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
N <- matrix(data=c( 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,  #1
                    0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,  #2
                    0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,  #3
                    0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,  #4
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #5
                    0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #6
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #7
                    0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,  #8
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ),#9
            nrow=9, ncol=9)
```

For clarity, here are the neighbors of neighbors in `A` that become the information stored in `N`.

```
#1: 9
#2: 6
#3: 4, 8
#4: 8, 3
#5: -
#6: 2
#7: -
#8: 3, 4
#9: 1
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604702/in-an-adjacency-matrix-how-to-find-a-given-vertexs-neighbors-neighbors) asks a similar question, but uses a different language and involves a slightly different solution.

Note: the ideal solution would scale to networks with 100 nodes and run tens of thousands of times, so I'm hoping for a solution that's efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple summary of the distances table.

```
library(igraph)
g = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(A, mode = "undirected")
dists = distances(g)

(result = ifelse(dists == 2, 1, 0))
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 # [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
 # [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 # [3,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
 # [4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0
 # [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 # [6,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 # [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 # [8,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
 # [9,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

And this easily extends to 2 steps away, 3 steps away, etc, however
the distances table will give *shortest-path* length, so if you look at lengths > 1 and your graph has cycles, this will only look at the shortest path.

Comment: nice `distances` option, +1!

Comment: Same to you - I would imagine in a large graph `ego` will be quite a bit quicker.

Comment: yes, I guess so, but yours would be more efficient when requiring adjacency matrix as the output, cheers!

Comment: This is the least efficient solution though. For a large graph, it is going to be completely infeasible due to having to traverse the _entire_ graph as many times as the vertex count. It has quadratic complexity in the number of vertices. In comparison, @ThomasIsCoding's solution has linear complexity and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: (Of course, if working with _dense_ matrices, then the complexity is technically always quadratic, simply due to the number of elements in the matrix. Thus, work with graph objects or sparse matrices.)

Comment: P.S. It will be possible to make this solution efficient as well once we get around to implementing a distance cutoff for shortest path calculations: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/720

Comment: Strong agree with all points in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the code below using `ego`

```
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(A, "undirected")
v <- rep(0, vcount(g))
N <- sapply(ego(g, order = 2, mindist = 2), function(k) replace(v, k, 1))
```

and you will obtain

```
> N
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

or a more compact result

```
> ego(g, order = 2, mindist = 2)
[[1]]
+ 1/9 vertex, from da0d22c:
[1] 9

[[2]]
+ 1/9 vertex, from da0d22c:
[1] 6

[[3]]
+ 2/9 vertices, from da0d22c:
[1] 4 8

[[4]]
+ 2/9 vertices, from da0d22c:
[1] 3 8

[[5]]
+ 0/9 vertices, from da0d22c:

[[6]]
+ 1/9 vertex, from da0d22c:
[1] 2

[[7]]
+ 0/9 vertices, from da0d22c:

[[8]]
+ 2/9 vertices, from da0d22c:
[1] 3 4

[[9]]
+ 1/9 vertex, from da0d22c:
[1] 1
```

Comment: You can convert the result of `ego` back to a graph using `graph_from_adj_list()`, which provides for a more compact solution.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it is more compact :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply square the adjacency matrix. (A^2)_ij gives the number of walks of length 2 between vertices i and j.

Note that walks can turn around and go back through the same edge where they came from. Thus the diagonal of A^2 contains the degrees: move along an edge and go back.

```
B <- A %*% A
diag(B) <- 0 # zero the diagonal
B <- 1*(B>0) # replace non-zero elements with 1s
```

Comment: Good idea of using walk length of 2. Here might be a golfed one-liner `+!!`diag<-`(crossprod(A), 0)`

Comment: This is a fantastic solution. The others produce viable output when there are NAs in the matrix - can this be generalized to accommodate NAs as well? I might post another Q for this solution.

Comment: @J.Q What would you do with `NA`s, how do you interpret them? A word of warning: the other solutions do not in fact handle `NA`s. igraph does not support `NA` values as weights, and future versions will stop with an error when a `NA` is present. Right now, even though there is no error thrown for `NA`s, there are no guarantees about what might happen if you pass them in. In the worst case, it will lead to a segmentation fault.